# Arduino isp bootloader burning

Tags: arduino

In earlier versions of the Arduino IDE there was a option to burn a the bootloader using an Arduino as the programmer. As of current there is only a burn bootloader option. Was the burn using a Arduino as a isp integrated into the still existing one, or did it disappear?

Comment: Sorry @user1153140, welcome to *Robotics* but I'm afraid that this question does not appear to be about Robotics.